# Validating elements of an ArrayList to match a parameter (Java)

Tags: java, validation, arraylist

I need a method that checks that at least 1 element of a list matches a parameter. I've figured it out, but this code is poor and slow.

```
private static void validateAdvertisements(List<Advertisement> advertisements) {
    List<Advertisement> inactiveAdvertisements = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Advertisement advertisement : advertisements)
        if (!advertisement.isActive()) inactiveAdvertisements.add(advertisement);

    if (inactiveAdvertisements.size() == advertisements.size()) throw new NoAdvertisementAvailableException();
}
```

Is there a getter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your logic *short-circuit*.

Since you need to throw an exception only if there are no active `Advertisement` instances in the list, when the first active element is encountered - break out from the loop.

```
private static void validateAdvertisements(List<Advertisement> advertisements) {
    boolean isActiveNotFound = true;
        
    for (Advertisement advertisement : advertisements) {
        if (advertisement.isActive()) isActiveNotFound = false;
        break;
    }
        
    if (isActiveNotFound) throw new NoAdvertisementAvailableException();
}
```

A stream-based solution using [`Stream.noneMatch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)), this operation is *short-circuit* and exception would be thrown only if there are no active objects.

```
private static void validateAdvertisements(List<Advertisement> advertisements) {
    boolean isActiveNotFound = advertisements.stream()
        .noneMatch(Advertisement::isActive);
        
    if (isActiveNotFound) throw new NoAdvertisementAvailableException();
}
```

In case if `NoAdvertisementAvailableException` is a *runtime exception*, it can be propagated outside the functions implementing standard functional interfaces from the JDK, like `Runnable`.

Here's an example that makes use of the combination [`Stream.findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) + [`Optional.ifPresentOrElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable)):

```
private static void validateAdvertisements(List<Advertisement> advertisements) {
    advertisements.stream()
        .filter(Advertisement::isActive)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresentOrElse(s -> {},
            () -> { throw new NoAdvertisementAvailableException(); }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank, but that's still quit not what I want. Is there, maybe, a stream method for that?

Comment: @Aleksandr `NoAdvertisementAvailableException` - is a *runtime* exception or *checked* exception?

Comment: It's a Runtime exception

Comment: @Aleksandr Then it's doable in a single stream-statement (see the code at the very end of the answer). But I would rather recommend `noneMatch()` since it's more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with the solution using Streams

```
private static void validateAdvertisements(List<Advertisement> advertisements) {
    if (advertisements.stream().noneMatch(Advertisement::isActive)) throw new NoVideoAvailableException();
}
```